# When I add third party dependencies I get a manifest merger fail, what should I do to fix this?

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
>   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

app.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dharquissandas.budget"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
            maven{
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dharquissandas.budget">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".add_expense"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_expense"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".add_income"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_income"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This was working and then suddenly it stopped working when I wanted to work on the app again. What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: check and maintain the same version of library in all modules of your project. In the same way my issue is fixed.

Answer (score 14):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This helped me, add this to your build.gradle and make sure you are using the same versions as '26.0.1'.

Comment: You are my life saver !

Comment: This helped me out with a similar Manifest Merger issue when I introduced Android Arch Lifecycle support to my app. I put the `configurations.all {}` block within my gradle's `dependencies {}` scope.  
These posts were helpful too:  
[Github - NativeScript Merger Error](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4677)  
[Github - Material Dialogs Merger Error](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/1451)

Answer (score 9):

You can try follow the suggestion adding a meta-data to your manifest:

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Add this meta-data using your version (26.0.2). In my case, I used version 26.1.0 and it worked:

```
<meta-data
    tools:replace="android:value"
    android:name="android.support.VERSION"
    android:value="26.1.0" />
```

Comment: Changed value to my current version and added this to the wear manifest. Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use same version for all support library and use below dependency in your gradle

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile ('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'com.google.android'
}
compile ('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'com.google.android'
}
```

Comment: That did not seem to work I got the same error as before

Comment: Did you add apply plugin: 'com.android.application' top of your build.gradle. if not .please add

Comment: could you please try 25.3.1 instead of 26.+ .and let me know the result

Comment: I get failed to resolve, and pressing on install and sync results in nothing happening

Answer (score 2):

As I understand `com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7` uses `26.0.1` so you have to use it too while material dialogs are not upgraded. Try to set exact versions instead of `+` for support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I changed 26.0.1 to 26.0.2 and it worked

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answerers for giving me a clue. However, none of the above answers worked out for me.

Instead, I changed support library to a different version (`26.1.0`) and now it works like a charm!

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Hope this would be useful for anyone with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Add This code on to your gradle file**

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar exception when use androidx libraries, added in gradle.properties resolved problem for me with dependencies:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```